# Multi-parameter type synonym instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible (and how) to define class instances for multi-parameter type synonyms.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

type F a b = a -> b
data DF a b = DF (a -> b)

class C c a b where
    doc :: c a b -> a -> b
```

It works for a multi-param type instance:

```
instance C DF a b where
    doc (DF f) x = f x
```

But it doesn't work for type synonyms:

```
-- ERROR:
--
-- Type synonym `F' should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
-- In the instance declaration for `C F a b'
--
instance C F a b where
    doc f x = f x
```

Is it possible to define a type class instance for `F`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible as written. Type synonyms must in general be fully applied to use them, especially [as a type class parameter](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#flexible-instance-head).

Note that if you can eta-reduce the type synonym enough an instance is possible; it's the synonym which must be fully applied, not the type it refers to. So this would work:

```
type F = (->)

instance C F a b where
    doc f x = f x
```

There is [a `LiberalTypeSynonyms` extension that relaxes some of the rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#type-synonyms) about expanding type synonyms, but it doesn't help here--it only lets you do things like give a partially-applied type synonym as a type parameter of another type synonym. Everything must still be fully expanded to use otherwise.

To see one reason why this restriction is necessary, consider the following type synonym:

```
type Flip f a b = f b a
```

And the following instance:

```
instance Functor (Flip Either a) where
    fmap _ (Right x) = Right x
    fmap f (Left x) = Left (f x)
```

Recall that there's also an instance `Functor (Either a)` which does the same thing, except mirrored. Both are sensible `Functor` instances.

Keeping in mind that unlike `newtype`, type synonyms are considered the same as the type they refer to, what should the value of the expression `fmap not (Right True :: Either Bool Bool)` be?

Answer (score 3):

Type synonyms have to be fully applied for an instance to be able to be defined for them.  The kind of `F` is not `* -> * -> *`, as one might expect, but instead invalid until two more type arguments are supplied.  Try

```
type F = (->)
```

instead.