# redefine instance for Either with specific type

Tags: haskell

I have this type synonym :

```
type ParseResult a = Either [CompilerError] (a, [CompilerWarning])
```

Where `CompilerError` and `CompilerWarning` are data types.

Now I know that Either has instance for `Functor` and `Applicative` but the instance for `Functor` applies `fmap` on the tuple `(a,[CompilerWarning])`, I want to redefine the instance for this type synonym so that `fmap` applies on `a` not the whole tuple, the same goes for `Applicative`.

If I use `newtype` I will have to put `ParseResult` all over the place and I've written a lot of code already.

I'm aware I need `TypeSynonymInstances` but I faced the same problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059948/multi-parameter-type-synonym-instances) question, from the question I think I need to define my type synonym like this :

```
type ParseResult = ...
```

I need to fill `...`, I don't know how to make the right side of kind `* -> *` with `Either` and the `tuple`, I tried `Either [CompilerError] ((,) [CompilerWarning])` but this has two problems : first `CompilerWarning` is the first element and I need it to be the second(so that I don't have to change a lot of code), second I get this message :

> • Expecting one more argument to ‘(,) [CompilerWarning]’
>         Expected a type, but ‘(,) [CompilerWarning]’ has kind ‘* -> *’
>       • In the second argument of ‘Either’, namely
>           ‘(,) [CompilerWarning]’
>         In the type ‘Either [CompilerError] ((,) [CompilerWarning])’
>         In the type declaration for ‘ParseResult’

What's the best, least expensive solution to this problem ?

Comment: Make `ParseResult` a `newtype` instead of a type alias. That way, you can define your own instances on it without conflicting with the ones that are already defined for `Either`.

Comment: If you can change your data type to `Either [CompileError] ([CompilerWarning], a)`, you can simply `fmap` twice: `(fmap . fmap) (+1) (Right ([], 1))` evaluates to `Right ([], 2)`.

Comment: I don't really understand how TypeSynonymInstances causes so much confusion. All it does is replace a type synonym in an instance head with its expansion. You can just as well do that yourself, so you can never need TypeSynonymInstances.

Comment: Aside from the evil of redefinition, there is absolutely no way to define a `Functor` instance for `Either` that does what you want. I urge you to switch to a newtype, or even a data type without `Either`, and consider where you want to draw the abstraction line to make your package make sense and reuse as much existing code as you can.

Comment: Consider something like `data CompResult a = CompFailed [CompilerError] | CompSucceeded a [CompilerWarning] deriving (Functor)`. You can easily write `Either`-like `Applicative`, `Monad`, and probably `MonadError` instances.

Comment: You may like the existing `WriterT [CompilerWarning] (Except [CompilerError])` monad. It offers `throwError` in place of your `Left`, `return` in place of your `Right . flip (,) []`, and `tell` in place of your `Right . (,) ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of both `Either` and `(,)` being *bifunctors*, not just functors. This means using `second . first` instead of `fmap` to apply a function to the value of type `a`.

```
> import Data.Bifunctor
> (second . first) (+1) (Right (1, []))
Right (2, [])
> (second . first) (+1) (Left ["oops"])
Left ["oops"]
```

`first f (x, y)` is equivalent to `(f x, y)`.

`second f (Right x)` is equivalent to `Right f x`, while `second f (Left y)` is equivalent to `Left y`.

Putting them together, you can see that

```
(second . first) (+1) (Right (1, [])) == second (first (+1)) (Right (1, []))
                                      == Right $ first (+1) (1, [])
                                      == Right ((+1) 1, [])
                                      == Right (2, [])
```

If you have a `Left` instead, nothing happens.

```
(second . first) (+1) (Left ["oops"]) == second (first (+1)) (Left ["oops"])
                                      == Left ["oops"]
```

---

Since `fmap` is the same as `second` for `Either`, this means you can still  use `fmap`. You just need to wrap the function with `first` before using it.

```
(second . first) f == second (first f)
                   == fmap (first f)
```

Thus

```
> import Data.Bifunctor
> fmap (first (+1)) (Right (1, []))
Right (2, [])
> fmap (first (+1)) (Left ["oops"])
Left ["oops"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't redefine existing instances (and it would be terrible if you could).

Your options are:

- Make `ParseResult` a real type, either using `newtype` or something like

  ```
  data ParseResult a = Failure [CompilerError] | Success a [CompilerWarning]
  ```

  and define instances for it.
- Don't bother with type classes at all, and just define functions like

  ```
  mapParseResult :: (a -> b) -> ParseResult a -> ParseResult b
  ```